# Rails accessing a record using belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model that has_many hacks and hack belongs_to user.  Hack has a field user_id.

I have a static_pages_controller with a home action:

```
def home
  @hacks = Hack.all
  @users = User.all
end
```

The user model is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  has_many :hacks
end
```

The hack model is:

```
class Hack < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hack_name, :serial_ids, :commentary

  has_many :hacktions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :serials, through: :hacktions
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope order: 'hacks.created_at DESC'

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :hack_name, use: :slugged
end
```

In the view I want to loop through the hacks and then identify the user that is associated with it:

```
<% @hacks.each do |h| %>
  <span><%= @users.find(h.user_id).username %>
  <div class = "home-date"><%=  h.created_at.strftime("%B %m, %Y - %I:%M %p")  %><%=   image_tag("housing.png") %></div>
  <div class = "home-title"><%= link_to h.hack_name, hack_path(h) %></div>
  <div class = "commentary lead"><%= markdown(h.commentary) %></div>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 undefined method `username' for #<Enumerator:0x007fd5078ac7b0>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here.  FYI: username is an accessible field from the user model.

Comment: show your models and relations

Comment: Thanks sanny Sin, alestanis rightfully discovered that I needed to put first before the call to username.

Comment: @sanny Sin I've updated my models in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `first` on the results of your `find`:

```
@user.find(h.serial_id).first.username
```

Comment: Waiting the required 9 minutes until I can mark this as answered. Curious, why does this work?

Comment: Because when you use `find` or `where` it returns a Criteria, not an object. When you call `first` on a Criteria, it returns the first found object. You can also call `last` or `all` for example. You should try it in the console, you will see the type and characteristics of a Criteria.

Comment: I suspect this will use the wrong id (the hack id) when retrieving the user.  It will seem to work but then the data will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<span><%= @user.find(h.serial_id).username %>
```

to

```
<span><%= @user.find_by_serial_id(h.serial_id).username %>
```

Comment: I corrected my original post to reflect that I'm using h.user_id not h.serial.id.  If I use @users.find_by_user_id(h.user_id), I get undefined method `find_by_user_id' for #<Array:0x007fd502d6a5e0> and if I use @user.find_by_user_id(h.user_id) I get undefined method `find_by_user_id' for nil:NilClass.